# DAX subquery measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I'm struggling with a DAX query and wondered if you could help?

Consider this table (or visualisation) called 'Builds':

```
Build....App....Status
Build1...App1...UAT
Build1...App2...Complete
Build2...App1...Complete
Build2...App2...Complete
```

I would like to add a measure column called 'AppsOutstanding' to show a count of Apps for that Build that aren't 'Complete'.  Like so:

```
Build....App....Status......AppsOutstanding
Build1...App1...UAT.........1
Build1...App2...Complete....1
Build2...App1...Complete....0
Build2...App2...Complete....0
```

I almost need to do a 'subquery' measure!?  Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Builds
WHERE Build = [The Build In This Row]
AND Status <> 'Complete'
```

I'm a bit stumped how to translate this into DAX?  Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
AppsUnavailable = CALCULATE (
    count(Builds[Build]),
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE ( Builds,Builds[Status] ),
        Builds[Status] <> "Complete"
    ))
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've tried this, but the count isn't working, and also this DAX filters "Complete" statuses out of my actual results!  Which i don't want.  I only want to filter the "Complete" statuses out of my count measure....

```
AppsUnavailable =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Builds[Build] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Build] ),
        Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Status] ),
        Builds[Status] <> "Complete"
    )
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.  I've really dumbed it down to just find other 'Builds' with the same name, and it still only returns 1's!

```
AppsUnavailable =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Builds[Build] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Build] ),
        Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )
    )
)
```

**UPDATE 3**

This query (when testing on a single table (no joins) sample) produces this:

```
Build....App....Status......AppsOutstanding
Build1...App1...UAT.........1
Build1...App2...Complete....0
Build1...App2...UAT.........1
Build2...App1...Complete....0
Build2...App2...Complete....0
```

But i actually need this:

```
Build....App....Status......AppsOutstanding
Build1...App1...UAT.........2
Build1...App2...Complete....0
Build1...App2...UAT.........2
Build2...App1...Complete....0
Build2...App2...Complete....0
```

So Build1 has 2 Apps that are not complete.

I then need to look into why I'm getting all 1's in the 'live' environment.  It must be to do with filtering on 2 tables as opposed to 1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace [The Build In This Row] with SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] ).
Try this:

```
AppsUnavailable =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Builds[App] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Status], Builds[Build] ),
        Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )
            && Builds[Status] <> "Complete"
    )
) + 0
```

[image]
powerBI Table visualization internal use SUMMARIZECOLUMNS which is removed row without data from the measure. You have 2 options:
-Right click on GroupBy Column -> "Show item with no data"
-Add +0 to calculation after the last parenthesis

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( YourTable[App] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( YourTable[App], YourTable[Build], YourTable[Status] ),
        YourTable[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( YourTable[Build] )
            && YourTable[Status] <> "Complete"
    )
) + 0
```

Comment: Ahh.  I probably dumbed down my example too much for the sake of this question - apologies.  In reality, the 'Build' and 'Status' columns are from two separate tables in the visualisation.  Hence the 'ALL' function doesn't like it....

Comment: I've tried separating your filters (so 2 filters now for Calculate) and it's chugging away....I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: if the columns are in different tables then you have to use the FILTER option twice as you write.

Comment: Updated my original question.  I couldn't get that to work properly...

Comment: Not working I'm afraid.  I've added the other filter too. It just returns 1's mostly.

Comment: In my example I COUNT ( Builds[App] ) in your COUNT ( Builds[Build] ); What do you really want to count?? Mayby try to reproduced my dummy dataset and test this MEASURE

Comment: Hi - I've added another update (update 3) above to clarify....thanks!

Comment: make a change in ALL to:

ALL ( YourTable[App], YourTable[Build], YourTable[Status] )

Comment: Thanks.  I can confirm that your query works perfectly on my single-table sample.  If you update your answer I will mark it as an answer.  However, do you know why it doesn't work on a visualisation table that has joined tables?  It seems to just return zeros.  I basically added another filter (one filter for each table) like in my first update above....

Comment: sorry, i noticed you have already updated your answer.  Let me know if you can shed any light on why it doesn't work across a joined dataset please....

Comment: Without additional details is hard to guess what is not working. Provide more info about your schema, table- column - relationship. What you put into visual? You use measure code from your question or you modified something?