# Power BI, DAX, Many-to-one and relational tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I previously asked a question here:
[DAX subquery measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671786/dax-subquery-measure/64671937#comment114424942_64671937)

for instruction on how to create a specific measure column for a visualisation.  To keep the example simple, I kept it to one fictitious table and the DAX query worked really well.

In reality, however, the visualisation that the measure column is for is made up of multiple joined tables.  And the results of the DAX query unexpectedly produced all zeros!  So I'll refactor my example here for more help...

**Requirement**

I want a count of how many 'Apps' are not equal to 'Complete' for a specific 'Build'.

**Data Model**

```
Builds
Build
App

Apps
App
Status
```

**Sample Data**

**Builds**

```
Build...........App
Build1..........App1
Build1..........App2
Build1..........App9
Build2..........App3
Build3..........App1
Build3..........App5
Build3..........App8
Build3..........App9
```

**Apps**

```
App...........Status
App1..........UAT
App2..........Complete
App9..........New
App3..........Complete
App5..........UAT
App8..........Complete
```

**Relationship**

The relationship is MANY Builds.App to ONE Apps.App.

**Visualisation Table**

This is my visualisation - note the different tables:

```
Builds.Build....Builds.App....Apps.Status
Build1..........App1..........UAT
Build1..........App2..........Complete
Build1..........App9..........New
Build2..........App3..........Complete
Build3..........App1..........UAT
Build3..........App5..........UAT
Build3..........App8..........Complete
Build3..........App9..........New
```

This is my required results:

```
Builds.Build....Builds.App....Apps.Status....AppsNotCompleteForBuild
Build1..........App1..........UAT............2
Build1..........App2..........Complete.......2
Build1..........App9..........New............2
Build2..........App3..........Complete.......0
Build3..........App1..........UAT............3
Build3..........App5..........UAT............3
Build3..........App8..........Complete.......3
Build3..........App9..........New............3
```

**ATTEMPT 1** (Not working!)

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Builds[App] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Build], Builds[App] ),
        Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )            
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Apps[Status] ),
        Apps[Status] <> "Complete"
    )
) + 0
```

**ATTEMPT 2** (Not working!)

```
Measure 5 = CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Builds[App] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Builds[Build] ),
        Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )            
    ),
    FILTER (RELATEDTABLE(Apps),
    Apps[Status] <> "Complete")
) + 0
```

**ATTEMPT 3** (Not working!)

```
Measure5 = CALCULATE (
   COUNTAX(FILTER( Builds 
            ,  RELATED(Apps[Status]) <>"Complete"  
               && Builds[Build] = SELECTEDVALUE(Builds[Build])
             )  
     ,Builds[App])
) + 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using these tables with a many to one relationship between Builds and Apps

```
Builds = 
DATATABLE(
    "Build", STRING,
    "App", STRING,
    {
        { "Build1", "App1" },
        { "Build1", "App2" },
        { "Build1", "App9" },
        { "Build2", "App3" },
        { "Build3", "App1" },
        { "Build3", "App5" },
        { "Build3", "App8" },
        { "Build3", "App9" }
    }
)

Apps = 
DATATABLE(
    "App", STRING,
    "Status", STRING,
    {
        { "App1", "UAT" },
        { "App2", "Complete" },
        { "App9", "New" },
        { "App3", "Complete" },
        { "App5", "UAT" },
        { "App8", "Complete" }
    }
)
```

we can write a dax measure that counts the number of apps per build that are not in "Complete" status. Since an app can have just one status, otherwise the many to one relationship would break, it's enough to filter out status = "Complete" when counting.

```
# not complete =
IF(
    HASONEVALUE( Builds[Build] ),
    VAR CurrentBuild =
        SELECTEDVALUE( Builds[Build] )
    RETURN
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                ALL( Builds ),
                Builds[Build] = CurrentBuild
                    && RELATED( Apps[Status] ) <> "Complete"
            )
        ) + 0
)
```

With this formula we can use a Table Visual to get this result

[image]

Edit: this will also handle cases where there are missing Apps in Apps table, just ignoring them

```
# not complete = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE( Builds[Build] ),
    VAR CurrentBuild =
        SELECTEDVALUE( Builds[Build] )
    VAR CurrentApp =
        SELECTEDVALUE( Apps[App] )
    VAR Result =
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                ALLNOBLANKROW( Builds ),
                Builds[Build] = CurrentBuild
                    && RELATED( Apps[Status] ) <> "Complete"
                    && NOT ISBLANK( RELATED( Apps[Status] ) )
            )
        ) + 0
    RETURN
        IF( NOT ISBLANK( SELECTEDVALUE( Apps[Status] ) ), Result )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.....it almost works perfectly!  One thing i might not have mentioned (apologies), is that not all apps in the Builds table will exist in the Apps table.  And i think this is counting those apps that are in Builds but not in Apps?  Does that make sense?

Comment: So I assumed these apps are to be ignored and therefore not counted

Comment: That works like a charm.  Thanks very much for your help the last couple of days.  There's no chance I could have developed that, but I've learnt a lot....

Comment: Like someone says: enjoy DAX :)

Comment: I've asked a further, related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774945/dax-to-count-based-on-a-measure-column

Comment: Hi @sergiom.  I've done some further testing, and if there is (for example) {Build1,App1...Build1,App1....Build1....App1} it counts it as 3 instead of 1 (1 App outstanding).  Is there any way to make the COUNTROWS based on a DISTINCT Builds.App?

Comment: At the moment i can only achieve 'similar' using CALCULATE, but that doesn't give me a value for each row.  I don't think i can use CALCULATE....