# DAX to count based on a measure column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I was kindly helped here:
[Power BI, DAX, Many-to-one and relational tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721062/power-bi-dax-many-to-one-and-relational-tables/64737702)

to produce a measure column based on this data:

```
Builds = 
DATATABLE(
    "Build", STRING,
    "App", STRING,
    {
        { "Build1", "App1" },
        { "Build1", "AppNotInApps1" },
        { "Build1", "App2" },
        { "Build1", "App9" },
        { "Build2", "App3" },
        { "Build2", "AppNotInApps2" },
        { "Build3", "App1" },
        { "Build3", "App5" },
        { "Build3", "App8" },
        { "Build3", "App9" },
        { "Build3", "AppNotInApps3" }
    }
)
 
Apps = 
DATATABLE(
    "App", STRING,
    "Status", STRING,
    {
        { "App1", "UAT" },
        { "App2", "Complete" },
        { "App9", "New" },
        { "App3", "Complete" },
        { "App5", "UAT" },
        { "App8", "Complete" }
    }
)
```

Many Builds have one Apps, joined on Builds.App = Apps.App.

The measure column (called 'incomplete') was this little beauty:

```
incomplete = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE( Builds[Build] ),
    VAR CurrentBuild =
        SELECTEDVALUE( Builds[Build] )
    VAR CurrentApp =
        SELECTEDVALUE( Apps[App] )
    VAR Result =
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                ALLNOBLANKROW( Builds ),
                Builds[Build] = CurrentBuild
                    && RELATED( Apps[Status] ) <> "Complete"
                    && NOT ISBLANK( RELATED( Apps[Status] ) )
            )
        ) + 0
    RETURN
        IF( NOT ISBLANK( SELECTEDVALUE( Apps[Status] ) ), Result )
)
```

Since this solution, I have also joined another table called Sites:

```
Sites = 
DATATABLE(
    "Site", STRING,
    "Build", STRING,
    {
        { "Site1", "Build1" },
        { "Site2", "Build1" },
        { "Site2", "Build3" }
    }
)
```

The join is on Sites.Build = Builds.Build.  And you'll notice that one build can appear in more than one site (don't ask!).

I have a slicer on the Sites.Site column.

Here is some sample data:

```
Site.....Build.....App.....Status.....Incomplete
Site1....Build1....App1....UAT........2
Site1....Build1....App2....Complete...2
Site1....Build1....App9....New........2
Site2....Build1....App2....Complete...0
Site2....Build3....App1....UAT........3
Site2....Build3....App5....UAT........3
Site2....Build3....App8....Complete...1
Site2....Build3....App9....New........3
```

The 'Incomplete' gives me a count of  how many Builds have a status that is not 'Complete'

What i want to do now (and this is the question) is have three cards in my BI view.

**Card one (a measure?)** - Count the DISTINCT number of Builds.Build that has an 'incomplete' count of 0.  Based on the data above, this value would be 1.  If i filtered this on Site1, this would be 0.

**Card two (a measure?)** - Count the DISTINCT number of Builds.Build that has an 'incomplete' count that is NOT equal to 0. Based on the data above, this value would be 2 (two distinct builds or Build1 and Build2).  If i filtered this on Site2, this would be 1 (Build3).

**Card three** - card one measure as a percentage of (card one measure plus card 2 measure)

I have filters (slicers) on my page so i need the measure to be dynamic.

I've tried this for card 1, but it doesn't give me the correct value?

```
comp = CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT(Builds[Build]),
FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Build), [incomplete] = 0))
```

And of course this for card 2:

```
comp = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Builds[Build]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Build), [incomplete] <> 0))
```

Is there something I'm missing before i try my card 3?

Comment: Can you give a few examples of results you expect from certain slicer selections? I think there may be some blank versus zero nuances to iron out.

Comment: Added further info...

Comment: I'm gathering ALLSELECTED applies all the current filters, so I am essentially 'COUNTING' the data in the current view?  At the moment the count in my 'real' data is returning too high....

Comment: This returns the right number of rows with a 0, but the count is not distinct build names (therefore the row count is too many): COUNTROWS(
    DISTINCT(
        FILTER(Builds,
        Builds[Incomplete] = 0
        )
    )
)

Comment: Hmm....this might be working: COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( VALUES (Builds[build] ), Builds[Incomplete] = 0 )
)

Comment: That looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The following DAX worked:

```
COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( VALUES (Builds[build] ), Builds[Incomplete] = 0 ) )
```

I'm not entirely sure why this did NOT work:

```
COUNTROWS( DISTINCT( FILTER(Builds, Builds[Incomplete] = 0 ) ) )
```